# gluDisk() function opengl

Tags: c++, syntax, glu

I am trying to create a function in my program that draws disk. I have a .h file called drawShape where I have all my drawing functions there. I am trying to add drawDisk to it, as seen below;howerver I keep getting an error saying that I have an undefined reference to gluNewQuadric and gluDisk. I have #included the glu.h library, so I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

```
void drawDisk(double inDiameter, double outDiameter, int vertSlices, int horizSlices)
{
    GLUquadricObj *disk;
    disk = gluNewQuadric();

    gluDisk(disk, inDiameter, outDiameter, vertSlices, horizSlices);
}
```

Here is my makefile as requested below in the comments section.

```
VRUI_MAKEDIR := /opt/local/Vrui-2.6/share/make
ifdef DEBUG
  VRUI_MAKEDIR := $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/debug
endif

INSTALLDIR := $(shell pwd)

# Set resource directory:
RESOURCEDIR = images

########################################################################
########################################################################

# Include definitions for the system environment and system-provided
# packages
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/SystemDefinitions
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.System
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Configuration.Vrui
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.Vrui

# Set installation directory structure:
BININSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(EXEDIR)
RESOURCEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(RESOURCEDIR)

########################################################################
########################################################################

PACKAGES = MYVRUI

########################################################################
########################################################################

ALL = $(EXEDIR)/SolarSystem     

.PHONY: all
all: $(ALL)

########################################################################
#'make clean'
########################################################################

.PHONY: extraclean
extraclean:

.PHONY: extrasqueakyclean
extrasqueakyclean:

# Include basic makefile
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/BasicMakefile

########################################################################
########################################################################
TEST = drawShape.cpp\
    solarSystem.cpp\
    planet.cpp\
    skybox.cpp

$(OBJDIR)/SolarSystem.o: CFLAGS += -DPICDIR='"$(RESOURCEINSTALLDIR)"'

$(EXEDIR)/SolarSystem: $(TEST:%.cpp=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)


    install: $(ALL)
    @echo Installing Vrui example programs in $(INSTALLDIR)...
    @install -d $(BININSTALLDIR)
    @install $(ALL) $(BININSTALLDIR)
    @install -d $(RESOURCEINSTALLDIR)
    @install $(RESOURCEDIR)/EarthTopography.png
```

Comment: #include only includes the header definitions. You need to tell your linker to link with the glu library. Perhaps something like "-lglu" in Unix/Mac, or adding whatever .lib file is there for GLU in Windows.

Comment: I am using a makefile to compile my program because it's using other libraries. If I compile using -lglu it complains that it's missing other directories.

Comment: I'm confused. -l is not an exclusive option (you can have more than one)... add -lglu AND your other libraries. If there are other missing libraries, you'll need to post the missing symbol error messages or nobody will know what's wrong for your specific case.

Comment: #include <Math/Math.h>
#include <Geometry/Geoid.h>
#include <GL/gl.h> 
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include "drawShape.h"
These are my #includes, when I run the compiler I get
drawShape.cpp:3:23: fatal error: Math/Math.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
I tried adding -lMath, but I still get the same thing. I don't really understand how they all work even though I have read a ton on the subject.

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues: edit your post to show your Makefile

Comment: @TiagoRodrigues: where do you specify that you link to `libGLU` ?

Comment: @FabienR: It's not a linking problem, it's an include problem. He should add a -I directive to CFLAGS while compiling the cpp files. (-I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wrote this function that lets me draw the disk and add texture to it.

```
void drawDisk(double radiusX, double eccentricity, int inRadius, int sideSmooth)
{   
double radiusY = 0.01;
double pi = Math::Constants<double>::pi;
double texY1 = 1.0f/double(inRadius);
double lat1 = 1.0f*pi/double(inRadius)-0.5f*pi;
double r1 = cosf(lat1);
double z1 = sinf(lat1);
for(int i = 2; i < inRadius; ++i)
{
    double r0 = r1;
    double z0 = z1;
    double texY0 = texY1;
    texY1 = double(i)/double(inRadius);
    lat1 = double(i)*pi/double(inRadius)-0.5f*pi;
    r1 = cosf(lat1);
    z1 = sinf(lat1);

    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for(int j=0; j <= sideSmooth; ++j)
    {
        double texX = double(j)/double(sideSmooth);
        double lng = double(j)*(2.0f*pi)/double(sideSmooth);
        double x1 = cosf(lng) * r1;
        double y1 = sinf(lng) * r1;
        glNormal3f(x1,y1,z1);
        glTexCoord2f(texX,texY1);
        glVertex3f(x1*radiusX,y1*radiusX*eccentricity,z1*radiusX*radiusY);
        double x0 = cosf(lng)*r0;
        double y0 = sinf(lng)*r0;
        glNormal3f(x0,y0,z0);
        glTexCoord2f(texX,texY0);
        glVertex3f(x0*radiusX,y0*radiusX*eccentricity,z0*radiusX*radiusY);
    }
    glEnd();
}

}
```